# Reverse lexicographical using heapq

Tags: python, string, comparator, heap, lexicographic

Essentially I am looking for an efficient way to implement custom comparators using `heapq`.

For instance `x = [('a',5),('c',3),('d',2),('e',1)]`

I could heapify it `heapq.heapify(x)` then pop the min value `heapq.heappop(x)` which would return `('a', 5)`. How can I make it such that it returns in reverse lexicographical order `('e', 1)`?
I know the convention when it comes to numbers is simply multiply the first element of the tuple by `-1`. Are there simple tricks like that when it comes to strings? I know I could potentially implement a map from a to z ... z to a but it sounds cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For numbers you would do something like this:

```
import heapq

x = [(1, 5), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)]
x = [(-a, b) for a, b in x]
heapq.heapify(x)
result = heapq.heappop(x)
result = (-result[0], result[1])
```

Similarly, I would do this with letters:

```
import heapq

x = [('a',5), ('c',3), ('d',2), ('e',1)]
x = [(-ord(a), b) for a, b in x]
heapq.heapify(x)
result = heapq.heappop(x)
result = (chr(-result[0]), result[1])
```

You may want to treat similarly also the second element of each tuple